Should there be Quantitative Finance Book Guides and Lists?
This question on a definitive C++ Book guide and list was very helpful to me. Could we have the same for Quantitative Finance topics as community wiki?
Before you vote to close or dismiss the question, please consider this quote from the C++ question:

Please leave this question open. It has been discussed on meta
  multiple times and the verdict was that, despite this question not
  fully adhering to current moderation guidelines, it does more good
  than harm. Also keep in mind that there are — literally! — thousands
  of links to this question all across the Internet.

Possible topics could be for example:

Financial Mathematics
Risk analysis and management
Time-series analysis
Fixed-income
Data aquisition, handling, cleansing
Portfolio and asset management

Related questions are:

Recommendations for books to understand the math in quantitative finance papers?
What books should any quantitative portfolio manager or risk manager have as reference?
What are some good technical and non-technical books for a math lover to get in to quantitative analysis?


There are a few reading lists on the web:
http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Quantitative-Finance-Reading-List
https://www.quantnet.com/threads/master-reading-list-for-quants-mfe-financial-engineering-students.535/
I'm pretty skeptical that these lists are useful though since "Quantitative Finance" is a broad field. HFT and exotic options pricing have no overlap, so any book list would have to be segregated into domain.

Yes, I agree, the lists should be segregated into domain. Also, a list which is maintained and collected here by multiple experts from the field has the possibility to be more universal and not just one persons opinion.

I agree with Anna, both lists you posted (and most others i've seen so far) seem to be primarily long, rather than helpful. A commented list that provides some context seems in order, and QFSO seems the best resource to achieve that.

I believe it is possible that those lists can be an addition to Quant.SE, despite the broad scope. For example this worked great, up to some point: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/392926/revisions
If we were to have such a list a lot of low quality questions can be avoided. Not only that, even seasoned quants can use such a list as a reference or to learn about unfamiliar topics.
